# No pressure on the clutch master and slave cylinder changed leaking on the bottom of the gear box

Tags: opel, astra, clutch-cylinder

Opel astra 2007 1.4 slave and master cylinder replaced but still the leak on the gear box underneath can be seen when you pumping the clutch

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was the leak the reason to change out the master/slave in the first place? Have you checked the hose to ensure it's not cracked?